# Difference between numpy.shape() and X.shape

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between

```
np.shape(X[1])
```

and

```
X.shape[0]
```

where X is an array.

Comment: it's just a convenience shortcut. a lot of numpy functions have an ndarray equivalent

Comment: I was doing assignment of deep learning course on Coursera where i was supposed to return the second dimension of the array. When I used np.shape(X[1]) I got the wrong output(not any error but the output was wrong ) but the problem got resolved when X.shape[0]. Why this happened?

Comment: Show us `X.shape` and `X.dtype`.  The 2 expressions are not equivalent.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.  (And this has nothing to do with machine "learning" either.)

Answer (score 1):

`array.shape` and `np.shape(array)` are the same:

[<kbd>See on Numpy Docs</kbd>](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html)

Comment: Look at his 2 uses more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

`np.shape` is a function; `x.shape` is a property, that normally returns the same thing.

Make a sample array:

```
In [119]: x = np.ones((1,2,3),int)
In [120]: x
Out[120]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
In [121]: x.shape
Out[121]: (1, 2, 3)          # a tuple
In [122]: x.shape[1]
Out[122]: 2                  # select the 2nd element of the tuple
```

The function returns the same tuple:

```
In [123]: np.shape(x)
Out[123]: (1, 2, 3)
```

Here `x[0]` is performed first, returning a new array:

```
In [124]: np.shape(x[0])
Out[124]: (2, 3)
In [125]: x[0].shape
Out[125]: (2, 3)
```

`np.shape` can take a non-array, such as a list of lists

```
In [126]: np.shape([[1],[2]])
Out[126]: (2, 1)
```

But if you want the 2nd dimension, you could use `size`, which returns just one number (depending on the optional axis parameter):

```
In [127]: np.size(x,1)
Out[127]: 2
In [128]: np.size(x)
Out[128]: 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got the answer for my question. But i got another doubt , what do you mean by x[0] is performed first? Could you please explain w.r.t the example you have given

Comment: In Python, arguments to functions are evaluated before they are passed to the function.  `x[0]` makes a new array.  [124] and {125] give us the shape of that array.